# Manage Roles in React JS application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

What kind of libraries are you using for user role management in your React applications? Any kind of directions are welcome. By role managing I am mostly reffering to showing or hiding certain components of the application.

Comment: as in user roles?  wouldn't that typically be handled at the server level using something like Node, Django, Rails etc...?

Comment: Yes, but showing or hiding certain components based on user role?

Answer (score 1):

At the simplest level, I would think you would just reflect the user role in your state, and have components render (or not) accordingly.

If you want to completely hide the existence of privileged code from a non-privileged user, you may need to factor common code into a shared library between user and admin apps, or generate two separate bundles, and authenticate access to the bundles.

Either way, the important thing is that you securely authenticate requests that would change server state in privileged ways.

Comment: Really like the idea of separate bundles, but at the end solved the problem to completely rely on backend and render or not the component depending on the response from API.

Comment: ya, but how do you do it when you have a single page app?